# create Angular2 angular-cli project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am trying to create Angular2 project using angular-cli. I run, `npm install -g angular-cli` then I `ng new test`, it returns

> "'ng' is not recognized as an interal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file."

I check the directory, `C:\node\node_modules\npm\node_modules`. There was not angular-cli found. My npm version is 4.0.2 and my node version is 5.11.0. If you guys have same problem, could you help me how to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

From [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) docs

> Prerequisites
>
> Both the CLI and generated project have dependencies that require Node
>   6.9.0 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher.

You need to upgrade your node and npm first.

Comment: Yep, after this, I made it.

Answer (score 0):

1) As VadimB suggested, you need to upgrade node and npm versions. Install latest version of node from nodejs.org and make sure you choose minimum **Node 6.9.0** setup.

2) You are trying to run wrong command. 
Current version command is - `npm install -g @angular/cli` (Please note - **@** before angular/cli package in above command.)

3) After `@angular/cli` installation, you can use `ng help` or `ng -v` to check successful installation and version.

4) You are looking at wrong folder. Once installed successfully, `@angular\cli` will be available in `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\`

Answer (score 0):

**Installing Angular Dependencies**

- Install a stable version of [Node](https://nodejs.org/) (if not already installed) and verify the installation using `node -v`
- Install [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) using [command `npm install -g typescript`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html#download-links)
- Download and install [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) using command `npm install -g @angular/cli`

`Angular` is a component oriented framework. Many components needs to be created to make the whole application. A component is a group of [custom elements, `HTML` elements, `ShadowDOM` & `HTML` imports.](//xameeramir.github.io/Custom-Elements-Shadow-DOM-Templates-in-HTML-by-Examples/)

**Creating the Angular 4 app using Angular CLI**

To create a fresh new Angular 4 app, use command `ng new newAppName`. This command takes some time to execute.

`package.json` - takes care of the development and app dependencies / packages / commands to execute

`src\main.ts` - takes care of the scaffolding the entire

`src\app\app.module.ts` - any newly created module has to added to the `declarations` and services has to be provided to the `providers` key parameter  of the function `@NgModule` to make them accessible across the entire application

**Run the Angular 4 app using Angular CLI**

To run the freshly created app using CLI, use command `ng serve` which will run the app on http://localhost:4200/.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: I have done as xameeramir suggested but still this error is coming :

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '.../elliptic/-/ellipti c-'

Comment: I think angular cli is not installed properly in my laptop